# Best Way to Handle System-Wide QSettings in Multiple Classes

Tags: qt, static, settings, external, qsettings

I have multiple classes that all need to access QSettings. It would be nice to have some standardized keys should they not exist. It also needs to be system wide, which requires creating an instance of QSettings. My current implementation is a class that all the other classes include.

```
int Settings::serverRefreshRate() {
    return settings->value("server/refreshRate", 10000 /* default value*/).toInt();
}
```

Though this does mean including this class everywhere, which I believe will add overhead.

Would making this class external be a good idea? What about static?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you're likely to only have one instance of this class, I'd personally make it static and use the [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)